# CSS div size issue

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML/CSS for a image slideshow I've made, it all works ok. But I'm having a problem keeping the content inside the "content" div, any help to get it to stay in there instead of leaving its parameters would much appreciated. it's in the correct position, just the content div doesnt expand to accomodate the slideshow.

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>


#slideshow {
position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
}

#slideshow img { 
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute; top: 30; left: 70;
}
```

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You need units for your `top`s and `left`s

Comment: An example would be great.

Comment: Works fine without values, the position is not the issue, it's exactly where it should be. The example is there above, quite clearly...

Comment: Difficould to help you without seeing more of your code, please add what is missing here, then press update and post back: __http://jsfiddle.net/ysvuN/__ - if you add also the Mootools code you will get the help you need.

Comment: Why would I post the Mootools code for a CSS/HTML issue? Surely that should suffice.

Comment: @Dunney, I think about your Mootools question yesterday. Then you get help. But, hey, its your choice. The more you post here the more clear it is. We are here to help

Answer (score 1):

```
#slideshow img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;
}                              ^^          ^^ you were missing the px
```

If the value is not 0 , then you need to include px or %

the only other thing I can suggest based on the code you provided and didn't provide is this

```
.content {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Just moves the image slideshow to the wrong position, and the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#slideshow {
position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```